# Custom Overlays - Google Maps V2 - Android - Trails

Tags: java, android, google-maps-android-api-2, android-maps-v2

I'm trying to use some of my custom overlays from GMaps V1.1 and have a custom overlay that can be used in my GMaps V2 MapView. I've read some tutorials on using Markers to add custom overlays however that's not what I want to.  I want to draw a line a certain color depending on speed.  How can I add this custom overlay to map?  I basically trying to draw a polyline where ever a person goes location-wise.

Comment: hi did you found the concept to draw different colored polyline in map in android

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[`GoogleMap.addPolyline`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/GoogleMap#addPolyline%28com.google.android.gms.maps.model.PolylineOptions%29) is your friend.

Anyway it would be good if you just forget all the code you wrote for API v1. These APIs are not compatible.